# Boundedness of a family of analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $F$ is a family of real analytic functions on an interval $(-a,a)$ of the real line ($a>0$). Suppose the Taylor series of $f$ about $0$ has a radius of convergence $r>0$, for  ALL $f\in F$. Can we say that $\sup_{F} |f(0)|$ is finite?

I tried to use the fact that the lim sup of $|\dfrac{d^{n} }{d x^{n}}f(0)|=1/r$ is finite, but it prove that $|\dfrac{d^{n}}{d x^{n}}f(0)|$ is bounded for $n>$ some $N$. How about the first term?

Comment: Wouldn't $F := \{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ such that $f_n(x) := n$ be a counterexample?

Comment: Maybe so... But I wanted with finite radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is real analytic and has radius of convergence $r >0$, then so does $\alpha f$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. Thus the family $F$ could contain $\alpha f$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and if $f(0) \neq 0$, then making $\alpha$ arbitrarily large shows that $\sup_F \lvert f(0) \rvert$ is infinite.